# I cannot link css file to html when rendering with inert

Tags: html, css, mongodb

I linked the css file to html(newPersonel.html) as follows:

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="newPersonel.css"></head>
```

my route definition as follows:

```
const start = async function() {

    await server.register(Inert);

    //*** Add route */
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/new',
        handler: {
            file: 'newPersonel.html'
        }
    });


    try {
        await server.start();
    }

    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);

};
start();
```

It is rendering the html page but doesn't get the link to css file and tries it as GET method.

GET http://localhost:5000/newPersonel.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please check if the css located in given url try to use url in new tab if not loaded then issue in css placed location

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sethuraman. But it is in there. Maybe you are indicating some other thing that I couldn't follow. html page coming but css in not applied. html and css files are both in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I skipped to add 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); 
Now it is solved.